# Check coherence between route and body data during .NET Core validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, validation, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to find the "best" way to check the coherence between data in the request URL and data in the body of the request.

For example, let's say we have this PUT endpoint:

```
https://host:port/foo/bar/{carId}
```

where I can pass a Car object as body:

```
class Car {
   string CarId { get; set; }
   string Brand { get; set; }
   int MaxSpeed { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

Now, in my controller I have something like this:

```
[HttpPut("foo/bar/{carId}")]
public async Task updateCar([FromRoute] string carId, [FromBody] Car car) {
    ...
}
```

**And I want to be sure that `carId` in the route matches the `CarId` property in the body.**

What is the "best" way to achieve this? Of course I could simply check with an `if` in the body controller, but since this is a validation task (or at least I think so), I'd like to have this logic in my validation layer.

---

### Personal ideas so far

*Ok, the question is over, here I'll just put some ideas I've tried or I want to try.*

---

I have a **custom action filter** to check the validation, and I'm trying to play with it in order to see if I can do something there, or add another custom action filter only where I want to check the coherence, but this doesn't look promising.

At the moment I've seen that in an action filter I have access to the controller method parameters through `context.ActionArguments` property, but I don't know how to check if these arguments were "bound arguments" (namely had some `[FromXXX]` attribute). If I could do this maybe I could check if there are arguments with the same name (or with a property with the same name), and then compare their values. But this seems very cumbersome and inconsistent.

---

I've read about **custom binders**, but I'm still scratching the surface (I hope to learn something more in the next few hours): can they be a possible solution?

Comment: The best way is not to put carId in a route. Just because of the curiosity , why do you need put carId twice?

Comment: @Serge Because one is part of the model of the car, and one is part of the route to identify the car uniquely. So IMHO both should be present. I've also read [something](https://dzone.com/articles/rest-api-path-vs-request-body-parameters#:~:text=So%2C%20to%20represent%20resource%20state%2C%20we%20need%20to%20send%20student_id%20in%20the%20request%20body%2C%20and%20to%20identify%20the%20resource%20uniquely%2C%20we%20need%20to%20send%20the%C2%A0student_id%C2%A0in%20path%20parameter.)  about this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for the link. But this article looks very weird to me. It was written a person, who never participated in any serious project , except "Hello world". IMHO you should forget about this article, it is not serious.

Comment: @Serge Thank you for the clarification! So how should I do this? Should I remove the duplicate info from the body or from the route? Or should I simply "overwrite" the information in the body with the one in the route? Also can you point me to some resource to learn these design stuff? I also tried to read [MS post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/best-practices/api-design) about REST API design, but it doesn't seem to talk about this.

Comment: You can not remove frombody since you need not only carId, so just remove "[FromRoute] string carId" and make your route [Route("~/foo/bar")]. I don't think that you need Put or Delete for example too,  if it is not your scholl project.  I always use only Get or Post and don't see any sense to put these word to route too. Don' t listen if somebody tells you about Rest principles, it is only good for a  textbook. The real controller can have about a hundred actions, and you will certainly not be able just to use 4 methods to implement these actions. Your actions should have meaningfull names.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class VerifyWithRouteParams : Attribute
{
   public string ParamName
   {
      get
      {
        return paramName;
      }
   }

   private readonly string paramName;

   public VerifyWithRouteParams(string paramName)
   {
       this.paramName = paramName;
   }
}
```

Consider you have a car model that is being recieved through body:

```
public class Car
{
    [VerifyWithRouteParams("carId")]
    public string CarId { set; get; }

    public string AnotherParam {set; get;}
}
```

You should have a default filter:

```
public class RouteBodyVerificationActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        // do something before the action executes
        if (context.ActionArguments != null && context.ActionArguments.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var arg in context.ActionArguments)
            {
                if (arg.Value == null) continue;

                bool isThereAnyObjectInArgumentsWithVerificationAttribute = arg.Value
                .GetType()
                .GetProperties()
                .Any(
                        x => x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(VerifyWithRouteParams), false).Any()
                    );

                if (isThereAnyObjectInArgumentsWithVerificationAttribute)
                {
                    foreach (var prop in arg.Value.GetType().GetProperties())
                    {
                        var verificationAttr = prop.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(VerifyWithRouteParams), false).FirstOrDefault() as VerifyWithRouteParams;
                        if (null == verificationAttr) continue;

                        string routeArgumentName = verificationAttr.ParamName;
                        context.ActionArguments.TryGetValue(routeArgumentName, out var routeArgumentValue);

                        if (null == routeArgumentValue)
                        {
                            context.ModelState.AddModelError("invalid argument value", routeArgumentName);
                        }

                        if (routeArgumentValue?.Equals(prop.GetValue(arg.Value)) != true)
                        {

                            context.ModelState.AddModelError("invalid argument value", routeArgumentName);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then you should add a default filter in startup:

```
services.AddControllers(cfg =>
{
    cfg.Filters.Add<RouteBodyVerificationActionFilter>();
});
```

Then you can check it by model validation errors in controller:

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
   return Content("invalid model");
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for this answer! I'll try this this afternoon. My only question is: I can use this filter only in specific endpoints instead of all, right? I simply have to add the action filter in a declarative way before the endpoint I want to have it active on?

Comment: Yes of course dear